# How to manualy enable error message from ModelAttribute and BindingResult in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, dto

Have a Controller with a function to save a record:

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public String create(
    @Valid @ModelAttribute NewShoeViewModel newShoeViewModel,
    BindingResult bindingResult
)
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the service layer is being developed by another person and uses a DTO object to create the new record and this has validation annotations, for example, to know if the name of a shoe is blank or not, the problem is that from my viewmodel I also do the same validation, but the service layer can throw a validation exception if the viewmodel does not match the DTO validation.

To handle these errors, if service tells me that the name has a different illegal length than my viewmodel I should handle that error, for now I am doing it as follows:

```java
@PostMapping("/create")
public String create(
    @Valid @ModelAttribute NewShoeViewModel newShoeViewModel,
    BindingResult bindingResult,
    Locale locale,
    // ...
)
{
    // ...

    try
    {
        shoesService.create(shoeDTO);
    }
    catch (ConstraintViolationException exception)
    {
        // ...
        
        if(/* name have a bad length from Service DTO */)
        {
            // Custom binding throw
            bindingResult.rejectValue(
                "name",
                "error.name.length",
                messageSource.getMessage(
                    "messages.shoes.name.bad_length",
                    null,
                    locale
                )
            );
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

The problem is several, first of all, the controller should not be handling the error messages, viewmodel already contains its own messages processed by BindingResult:

```java
public class NewShoeViewModel implements Serializable
{
    @NotEmpy
    @Size(min=3, max=128, message="{messages.shoes.name.bad_length}")
    private String name;
```

How can I get the validation to say that the name field failed but without sending the text from the controller **and calling the size error and not empty error**? just by making the validation fail manually, this way I can pass the service DTO errors to the viewmodel errors. In the official documentation `rejectValue` require the default messge but need recycle the viewmodel message, by example:

- Dto says: name error -> Set in the viewmodel: name error
- Dto says: description error -> Set in the viewmodel: description error

But keeping the original messages and codes of the viewmodel validation.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you are validating the same `dto` twice? at service and controller?

Comment: and `@Size` will handle the job of `@NotEmpty`. You don't need them both.